# Finding Macro in Confluence

Tags: macros, confluence

I have taken over a confluence project.  I am trying to update the Dashboard and I am editing the layout for that.

Could anyone point me in the direction of where to find the macros, example below.

`$helper.renderConfluenceMacro("{include:OP:_allspaces-column}")`

Thanks

Comment: I finally found the correct documentation on the Atlassian website.

Answer (score 0):

This is the **include** macro. It includes the **_allspaces-column** page from the space with a space key of **OP**.